# Bootstrap Placing Elements one under another

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, positioning

I'm using bootstrap to position some cards one near another but i'm not really able to do it because it always places the cards one under another.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class='card' style='width:20rem;'>
          <img class='card-img-top' src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtjjCv9pQRtLSNn-zjQrsdKnCFWVe-WSH7Rf_qJnXm99mrHTZL"
            alt='Card image cap'>
          <div class='card-body text-center'>
            <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Car</p>
            <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
              <li class='list-group-item'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="card" style='width:20rem;'>
          <img class='card-img-top' src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtjjCv9pQRtLSNn-zjQrsdKnCFWVe-WSH7Rf_qJnXm99mrHTZL"
            alt='Card image cap'>
          <div class='card-body text-center'>
            <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Car</p>
            <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
              <li class='list-group-item'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 offset-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically i need those 2 cards to be on the same row and one after another but i don't understand what's wrong.Are those cards too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your inline style definition for your cards: `width: 20rem`. Essentially, you're giving the card 2/12 of the grid to work with (`col-sm-2`) and then giving a hard definition of the card to have a width of 20rem, which forces the next card to take up the next line.

Also, you need to specify another row after your `col-8` declaration. Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class='card'>
            <img class='card-img-top' src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtjjCv9pQRtLSNn-zjQrsdKnCFWVe-WSH7Rf_qJnXm99mrHTZL" alt='Card image cap'>
            <div class='card-body text-center'>
              <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Car</p>
              <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
                <li class='list-group-item'>
                  <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                      <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                      <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card">
            <img class='card-img-top' src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtjjCv9pQRtLSNn-zjQrsdKnCFWVe-WSH7Rf_qJnXm99mrHTZL" alt='Card image cap'>
            <div class='card-body text-center'>
              <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Car</p>
              <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
                <li class='list-group-item'>
                  <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                      <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                      <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 offset-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```